# Bug in Math.SE reputation displayer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[image]

I have 2541 reputation at one place and 2526 reputation at another place.I have refreshed the page many times but it continues.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What should I do?

Wait.

The data is picked up from different sources and is not synchronized in real-time. Give it a few minutes and it will sync up.

Comment: Approximately how much time is expected?

Comment: A few minutes - shouldn't be long. Sometimes, the sync won't happen (race conditions, network glitch etc...), but the next time your reputation changes it will.

Comment: Problem solved...thanks!!